# How to use glob with a skip list

Tags: python, glob

I am trying to read a file with the same name in a series of directories using glob.glob but I want to skip some specific directories.
My directories names are like trj0001,..,trj0099 and I want to skip a list of them like: list = [trj0005, trj0009, trj0011, trj0056, trj0083].

I am currently using this line:

```
    files = glob.glob(r'my_dir/trj_00*/file.txt')
```

Any hint is appreciated.

Comment: `s = set(list_of_skip_files); [file for file in files if file not in s]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you to filter the list **after** using `glob`, using list comprehension which is quite readable, as follows:

```
import glob

files = glob.glob(r'my_dir/trj_00*/file.txt')
blackList = ['trj0005', 'trj0009', 'trj0011', 'trj0056', 'trj0083']
files = [f for f in files if all(bl not in f for bl in blackList)]

print(files)
```

Comment: Thanks! what about putting a list of skip directories? (I edited my question)

Comment: Perfect. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There is no easy way to skip certain files while using `glob` unless you want to match all files except files matching some pattern.

So you can explicitly skip it using `filter`

```
exclude_list = [trj0005, trj0009, trj0011, trj0056, trj0083]
files = filter(lambda path: not any(e in path for e in exclude_list), glob.glob(r'my_dir/trj_00*'))
```

Comment: Thanks! what about putting a list of skip directories? (I edited my question)

Comment: @Raha. Updated my answer